# What does the "since" mean?

Tags: prepositions, discourse-context

From BBC News:

> The US, Japan and South Korea say they have since defied the ruling.

In this sentence, there is a strange "since" that I cannot understand. In my view, "since" means ***from a particular time until the present***, but what does the word "since" here mean? In other words, I even cannot understand the structure of the sentence. Can anyone tell me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In this particular usage, think of it as *ever since [then/that point in time]*. I wouldn't advise that you should use *ever since then*, but that's all that it means. As for the rest, *say* is just a bare infinitive. Think of it as being similar to the present perfect: *The US, Japan and South Korea **have said** they have since [that time] defied the ruling.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of *since* is correct ‘from a particular time until the present’. What that ‘particular time’ is, however, does not appear in the sentence itself but in the preceding sentence:

> China said last week that all aircraft crossing through the zone must file flight plans and identify themselves or face "defensive emergency measures".
>
> The US, Japan and South Korea say they have since defied the ruling and flown military aircraft in the area.

That is, the US, Japan and South Korea say that **since China issued that [ruling]** they have defied it.

This may be understood in either a continuative or an existential sense (see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32)):

> CONTINUATIVE: The three nations have been defying the ruling continuously throughout the timespan from China's statement to the present.
>
> EXISTENTIAL: The three nations have defied the ruling at least once during the timespan from China's statement to the present.

Comment: If I knew you are around here, I might probably not post my answer. :) It took me quite too long checking out that web page.

Comment: Should I delete my answer? I'm not sure if OP will understand "the structure of the sentence" with just the aid of "since China issued that [ruling]". It's likely. But I'm not very sure.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Good gracious, no! Some readers will understand your answer better, some will understand mine better - the more the merrier!

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of **since** is correct.

Perhaps you might get confused with the sentence structure, and maybe also "which particular time" this "since" begins.

Let's look at the sentence. I will use parentheses to make it easier to understand,

> (The US, Japan and South Korea) say (they have since defied the ruling).

I believe that you already know that the word "they" refers to *"The US, Japan and South Korea"*.

---

Now let's analyze this clause:

> (they) (have **since** defied) (the ruling).

The verb is *"have defied"*. We also have the adverb *"since"* to indicate "since when they have defied the ruling". This implies that the reader should have already know this "when", usually from the previous sentences.

I found your news in BBC's website. Here are some sentences before the sentence you asked:

> China says it scrambled fighter jets to monitor US and Japanese planes as they flew in its newly declared air defence zone in the East China Sea on Friday.
>
> China said last week that all aircraft crossing through the zone must file flight plans and identify themselves or face "defensive emergency measures".

If I understand the news correctly, "the particular time" that our *"since"* starts from would refer to *"last week"*, or more specifically the last *"Friday"*.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of "since" in this context is "since then."

So we therefore look at what "then" refers. There was a ruling issued by the Chinese about its airspace on such-and-such a date and time. "Then" refers to this particular time.

So "since" has an implied antecendent, which is, "the time that the Chinese issued the airspace ruling."